# Python savefig: how to save the figure in a given path using savefig from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save the figures in a given path, and write the following code:

```
savefig('/Users/gaoyingqiang/Desktop/1-153Umlauf'+str(p)+'.png')
```

But in fact python only names the figures "1-153Umlauf1.png", and they are all saved on the desktop. How can I save the figures in the folder 1-153Umlauf?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If it's a folder, there seems to be a missing slash. It might be also better to use absolute paths or else it might be depending on your current-dir (e.g. read by ```os.getcwd()```). But by all means: bernie's recommendation of using os.path is the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
output_path = os.path.join('/Users/gaoyingqiang/Desktop/1-153Umlauf',str(p)+'.png')
```

Comment: how to combine the savefig with os.path.join? I'm new to programming so...

Comment: Oh I just figured it out! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Im getting an error `NameError: name 'p' is not defined` I think from the `,str(p)`. Am I missing anything? I am also doing an `import os` Thanks all!

Comment: @HenryHub: what code are you running? You might wish to open a new question.

Comment: iPython Jupiter Notebooks.. Will do Ill open up a new one and send a link